# Images are not showing on PDF after changing application pool setting on IIS Server

Tags: iis, application-pool, php-7.1, shared-directory, folder-access

We have one application hosted on Windows 2016 server and with this there is one shared drive as well which holds some images.

Recently we have changed application pool of the site and also added that user on shared file system.

After this change, when i generate a PDF which holds images from the shared drive , it is showing image on PDF file. It shows file not found. I was working before this change.

I do have one edit page which shows this same image. When I generate PDF of it , images are not getting displayed.

PDF Image file path Format is "\\xx.xx.xx.xx\path\to\folder\filename.jpg"

Not sure what we missed here for the permission.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application pool identity has been changed. Please set your application pool identity to a domain account that have permission to access the image file.

Maybe somewhere else need read/write permission .Process monitor could help in this case. Please add a filter to trace file not found exception or access denied error.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon